# Best way to use a class inside another class

Tags: php, class, oop, dependency-injection, traits

I've created this class that fetches all data of a post from database.

```
class Post {
    private $id;
    protected $conn;
    public $data;

    function __construct(\mysqli $conn) {
        $this->conn = $conn;
    }

    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getConnection() {
        return $this->conn;
    }

    public function getPost() {
        $query1 = $this->getConnection()->query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id=" . $this->id);

        if ($query1->num_rows == 1) {
            $this->data = $query1->fetch_object();
            return $this->data;
        }
    }

    public function setId($id) {
        $this->id = (int)$id;
    }
}
```

Along with post, I also need to fetch all data of the user who created the post. I've three ways to do this:

1) By calling the User class inside of the Post class.

```
    public function getPost() {
        $query1 = $this->getConnection()->query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id=" . $this->id);

        if ($query1->num_rows == 1) {
            $this->data = $query1->fetch_object();

            // Initiating User class
            $user = new User($this->getConnection());
            $user->setUserId($this->data->user_id);
            $this->data->user = $user->getUserInfo();

            return $this->data;
        }
    }
```

2) By extending the Post class with the User class.

```
class Post extends User {
    ....
```

Then calling methods from the User class

```
    public function getPost() {
        $query1 = $this->getConnection()->query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id=" . $this->id);

        if ($query1->num_rows == 1) {
            $this->data = $query1->fetch_object();

            // Calling methods from the User class
            $this->setUserId($this->data->user_id);
            $this->data->user = $this->getUserInfo();

            return $this->data;
        }
    }
```

3) By creating a User trait and using it in Post class.

```
class Post {
    use UserTrait;
    ....
```

Then calling methods from the User trait

```
    public function getPost() {
        $query1 = $this->getConnection()->query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id=" . $this->id);

        if ($query1->num_rows == 1) {
            $this->data = $query1->fetch_object();

            // Calling methods from the User trait
            $this->setUserId($this->data->user_id);
            $this->data->user = $this->getUserInfo();

            return $this->data;
        }
    }
```

Between these 3, which one is the best approach in terms of dependency injection, performance, and cleanliness of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question might get downvoted to hell because you're requesting an opinion, but I'll throw in my two cents.

You're basically building your own basic ORM. In that ORM you're dealing with entities. Different entities should be handled by different classes (Models), and there should be a 1:1 equivalence between the underlying DB table and the Model.

There are relations between your entities. Yous Post entity has an author that should be an instance of the User entity. However, you wouldn't say that the relation between the post table and the user table means they could be represented by the same Model, or different flavors of a parent Model.

If you used a full ORM (Doctrine, Propel, RedbeanPHP) you'd see that a relation such as the Post author means that, when using methods like `getById()` (in your case `getPost()` ) the retrieved Post entity will proceed to instance every depending entity by default.

In your case, instead of having `$this->data->user_id` the ORM would offer you a nested `$this->data->user` object so you wouldn't have to deal with that by yourself.

So, if you consider it's too soon to use an ORM, the first approach is easier to mantain and migrate when the time comes.

**Unrelated opinion**

At this point, to get a post info you need to do

```
$post = new Post($conn);
$post->setId($postid);
$postdata = $post->getPost();
```

If you changed your constructor and added a getById() method such that

```
function __construct(\mysqli $conn) {
    $this->conn = $conn;
    return $this;
}

public function getById($id) {
     $this->setId($id);
     return $this->getPost();
}
```

you could instead retrieve the post data in one line

```
$postdata=(new Post($conn))->getById($postid);
```

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what you're going to keep doing it. With the extended class was better deal if you're going to use permanent methods of other classes. If you need only a part of another class, then just call the class and its method.

CAREFUL: An extended class behaves as a single class. Here can be a lot of collisions occur if you have the same names of methods and functions.

Answer (score 0):

I think this depends on other aspects of your code.  Personally I would just extend the class User as I don't think using traits is necessary in this particular case.

There is a useful article here on using Traits in PHP -
[Using Traits in PHP 5.4](http://www.sitepoint.com/using-traits-in-php-5-4/)